# What is the gcc equivilant for Xlc '-qthreaded' compiler option?

Tags: gcc, aix, porting, xlc

I am currently porting my compiler from AIX XLC compiler to GCC compiler on AIX.

I want to know if there is an GCC equivalent compiler option available for the [-qthreaded](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGH3R_16.1.0/com.ibm.xlcpp161.aix.doc/compiler_ref/opt_threaded.html) (XLC).

Comment: It would be `-pthread`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`-pthread` is the closest GCC option for use cases where `-qthreaded` is applied for XL; however, it is not equivalent to the `-qthreaded` option for IBM XL.

The GCC documentation for `-pthread` merely states that it sets macros (http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#index-pthread) and modifies the link step (http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html#index-pthread-1). `-qthreaded` does not cause `_THREAD_SAFE` to be defined as a macro, nor does it cause `-lpthreads` to be present in the link step. GCC's `-pthread` is more like XL's `_r` invocations (which does set the macro and modify the link step).

What `-qthreaded` does is to disable optimizations that are unsafe for multithreaded programs. It appears that, at least historically, `-fno-tree-loop-if-convert-stores` would at least partially be a GCC equivalent to `-qthreaded`.